# PowerShell CompressArchive -Update into directory inside the zip file

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to update a file inside of a zip file, as I need to automate this for a number of zips.
My issue is that the file I need to update is inside a few directories inside the zip, such as:

myZip.zip -> dir1/dir2/file.txt

I'm trying to use the command such as

```
Compress-Archive -Path .\file.txt -Update -DestinationPath .\myZip.zip
```

But when I run that, the file gets added to the root of the zip file, rather than into the dir1/dir2/ directory as I need it to.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah you probably need to emulate the Zip structure to target the right ZipEntry. Try putting `file.txt` inside `dir1/dir2/` and then compress `dir1` with the `-Update` switch. That may work (do a copy of the Zip just in case)

Comment: you probably can't specify a path in the zip file because it is technically a *file* not a *folder*. So yeah you would likely have to emulate the zip structure and update that whole folder.

Comment: If that didn't work then your code might require a more manual labor using the .NET APIs directly

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon - running the following worked somewhat: mkdir ./dir1/dir2 cp file.txt ./dir1/dir2/ Compress-Archive -Path .\dir1 -Update -DestinationPath .\myZip.zip This successfully moved the file into the right subdirectory, but interestingly it hasn't updated the existing file, I now have 2 file.txt files in the directory Appreciate the help

Comment: I see, the file you're looking to update, are looking to replace it with a new file or append content to it?

Comment: I'm looking to replace the same file with an updated version, but was leading to a duplication. I've found a workaround which is to use the 7zip CLI to recursively delete this file from the zip, then use Compress-Archive to add the new file in. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Worked out that the -Path must reference the same directory structure as it is found in zip file.

My test zip has the following directory structure:

```
myZip.zip
-> dir1
-> -> dir2
-> -> -> dir3
-> -> -> -> myFile.txt
```

My reference directory is then defined as:

```
dir1
-> dir2
-> -> dir3
-> -> -> myFile.txt
```

I can then run

`Compress-Archive -Path .\dir1 -DestinationPath .\myZip.zip -Update`

And this puts the file into the right directory.

Thanks to @SantiagoSquarzon here, and @metablaster on a [related ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74544412/compress-archive-update-doesnt-update-the-file/74545092?noredirect=1#comment131590847_74545092)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can update the [`ZipArchiveEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry?view=net-6.0) using the .NET APIs directly, this method doesn't have a need on external applications or `Compress-Archive`. It also doesn't need to emulate the Zip structure to target the right file, instead, it needs you to target the right Zip Entry by passing the correct relative path (**`dir1/dir2/dir3/myFile.txt`**) as argument of [`.GetEntry(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.getentry?view=net-6.0).

```bash
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.IO.Compression

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression

$filestream = (Get-Item .\myZip.zip).Open([FileMode]::Open)
$ziparchive = [ZipArchive]::new($filestream, [ZipArchiveMode]::Update)
# relative path of the ZipEntry must be precise here
# ZipEntry path is relative, note the forward slashes are important
$zipentry   = $ziparchive.GetEntry('dir1/dir2/dir3/myFile.txt')
$wrappedstream = $zipentry.Open()
# this is the source file, used to replace the ZipEntry
$copyStream    = (Get-Item .\file.txt).OpenRead()
$copyStream.CopyTo($wrappedstream)
$wrappedstream, $copyStream, $ziparchive, $filestream | ForEach-Object Dispose
```