# Compress-Archive -Update doesn't update the file?

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm trying to create a simple script to update a file within a zip, but running into some issues.
MyZip.zip contains some subdirectories, and the file I want to update (myFile.txt) is inside dir1/dir2/dir3:

[initialZip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF9vB.png)

I'm then running the following command to try and update this file with a new version of myFile.txt (which is nested inside dir1/dir2/dir3 on my file system so that it gets updated into the right directory in the zip):

```
Compress-Archive -Path .\dir1 -Update -DestinationPath .\myZip.zip
```

But this is resulting in the new version of the file being added to the directory, but not replacing the old version:

[DuplicatedFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXj0U.png)

What doesn't make sense after this, is that when I then go and update the source file, and rerun the same command, the new version of the file is updated correctly, and it doesn't make a third one?

[UpdatedDuplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omN3r.png)

Why wouldn't this work for the original file in the zip?
Am I doing something wrong, or do I need to change how I'm doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`-Path` **parameter must reference same directory structure as it is found in zip file.**

My test zip has the following directory structure:

```
test.zip
-> a
-> -> b
-> -> -> c
-> -> -> -> test.txt
```

My reference directory which I want to merge into existing zip file for update has the following directory structure:

```
a
-> b
-> -> c
-> -> -> test.txt
```

Then I edit `test.txt` in `a\b\c` folder with new contents.

To put that update into `test.txt` in the zip archive I run:

```
Compress-Archive -Path .\a -DestinationPath .\test.zip -Update
```

And it works just fine.

Comment: Hi, yes I have replicated the file directory locally, so when I install the file it updates into the same directory as the existing file, but it doesn't overwrite the existing file, it's just adding to the same directory as a duplicate

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem but I see in your "duplicate" screenshot that file attributes and some other properties like "method" and "characteristics" are not same, maybe this can give you some hints?

Comment: I think that must be it. I've found a workaround which is that I can use the 7zip CLI to recursively delete this filename from the zip, and then use Compress-Archive to add the new file in. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that I have found is to use the [7zip CLI](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/delete.htm) to recursively delete the initial file:

```
./7z.exe d 'C:\Users\tboyle\Downloads\myZip.zip' 'myFile.txt' -r
```

And then use Compress-Archive to just add the new file in:

```
Compress-Archive -Path .\dir1 -Update -DestinationPath .\myZip.zip
```